# Generating Binary Permutations With Constraints

Tags: algorithm, scheduling, permutation

I am working on physician scheduling application, we are using linear programming and solvers like cplex/lindo to solve our model. Due to some modelling limitations we need to generate binary patterns for just night shifts.

Typically we generate one month schedule so lets consider we need to generate patterns for 30 days for night shift.

Night shift have some constraints like if a person is coming on consecutive night shifts then physician could not work for next five days. So bellow are some examples of constrains.

```
111000001111100000111110000011 Valid
111000001100000000111110000011 Valid
111010001111101000111110000011 Invalid
```

Also there are other constraints like number of ones in pattern should be less than some defined value, number of consecutive ones should be less than some defined value etc.

First i tried simple algorithm which starts form 0 and use bitwise operator and add one to get next permutation and check the next permutations against all constraints if not valid get the next permutation and ignore the invalid pattern. As this pattern is of length 30 bits (2<sup>30</sup> = 1073741824) so number of patterns are huge to check go my simple algorithm. I guess it will take more then 24 hours to find out all valid patterns.

Now my questions are

1. Which algorithm shall i use for the given problem which find all permutation with constraints applied in time efficient way?
2. Is this problem a exact cover problem? Can i apply algorithms like dancing links to the problem i am facing?
3. Kindly provide some links to read about the solution you propose for this problem?

Comment: Enumerating all binary pattern combinations for all night shifts of the entire planning window probably won't scale. At the very least, try cutting them up into smaller pieces of about 7 days (2 consecutive work days require 5 free days) or find a way to express the whole constraint as a single generic constraint (somewhat like [this](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-examples/src/main/resources/org/optaplanner/examples/nurserostering/solver/nurseRosteringScoreRules.drl)).

Comment: There are 12333800 patterns for 30 binary digits, with at most 5 consecutive ones, at least 5 consecutive zeros after consecutive ones, and at most 15 ones total. 34134 of which has exactly 15 ones.

Comment: If you truly want to generate all of the possible patterns, there should be a fairly simple recursive solution. But as Markus pointed out this could be a rather large number of patterns.

Answer (score 0):

I have found very good solution in "The Art of Computer Programming - Volume 4A – Combinatorial Algorithms, Part 1 by Donald Knuth" section "7.2.1.2 Algorithm G(General permutation generator). In it the author describes technique Bypassing unwanted blocks. I am implementing the algorithm with incremental generation a tree of feasible region and bypass any infeasible path. I am going to implement in a way like for example starting with node with value 0 and this node has two children 0 and 1 and again every node has children 0 and 1 on every addition of new child node we will check with our constraints set if it fails to comply with constraint do not add the child node for example if algorithm is going to add node at level 5 and the resultant string at level 5 is 11101 and because of night shift constraint "101" at end of 11101 does not comply with night shift rule then don't add level 5 node of value 1. Keep adding the child node until we have root nodes. So eventually we will have only feasible region as we have bypass the unwanted blocks. In this way i will never touch infeasible region.